# creating a custom serializer for large data classes

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization, ktor-client

I have a data class for a currency conversion rate response.

I keep getting this error:  Rejecting invocation, expected 76 argument registers, method signature has 78 or more ...

as you can see below. (the `Conversion Rates` class has more than 160 currency)

I"m using Ktor client, and my data classes looks like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "exchange")
@Serializable
data class Exchange(
    val base_code: String,
    @Contextual
    val conversion_rates: ConversionRates,
    val documentation: String,
    val result: String,
    val terms_of_use: String,
    @PrimaryKey
    val time_last_update_unix: Int,
    val time_last_update_utc: String,
    val time_next_update_unix: Int,
    val time_next_update_utc: String
)

@Serializable
data class ConversionRates(
    val AED: Double,
    val AFN: Double,
    val ALL: Double,
    val AMD: Double,
    val ANG: Double,
    val AOA: Double,
    val ARS: Double,
    val AUD: Double,
    val AWG: Double,
    val AZN: Double,
    val BAM: Double,
    val BBD: Double,
    val BDT: Double,
    val BGN: Double,
...
```

> failed with exception: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates$$serializer: com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates$$serializer.deserialize(kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder) failed to verify: com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates$$serializer.deserialize(kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder): [0x10F0] Rejecting invocation, expected 76 argument registers, method signature has 78 or more (declaration of 'com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates$$serializer' appears in /data/data/com.example.testingxml/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes7.dex)
> 2022-07-17 16:23:27.926  8855-8855  AndroidRuntime          com.example.testingxml               E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main

I tried to use hashmap/ TreeMap... that didn't work because Kotlin couldn't cast the response to it.

any solution?

*UPDATE*
The Json Response I get

```
{
 "result":"success",
 "documentation":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs",
 "terms_of_use":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/terms",
 "time_last_update_unix":1658016002,
 "time_last_update_utc":"Sun, 17 Jul 2022 00:00:02 +0000",
 "time_next_update_unix":1658102402,
 "time_next_update_utc":"Mon, 18 Jul 2022 00:00:02 +0000",
 "base_code":"USD",
 "conversion_rates":{
  "USD":1,
  "AED":3.6725,
  "AFN":87.9897,
  "ALL":116.9156,
  "AMD":413.3227,
  "ANG":1.7900,
  "AOA":431.4219,
  "ARS":127.5711,
  "AUD":1.4762,
  "AWG":1.7900,
  "AZN":1.6932,
  "BAM":1.9426,
  "BBD":2.0000,
  "BDT":93.1628,
  "BGN":1.9427,
  "BHD":0.3760,
  "BIF":2032.0309,
  "BMD":1.0000,
  "BND":1.3978,
  "BOB":6.8633,
  "BRL":5.4199,
  "BSD":1.0000,
  "BTN":79.8199,
  "BWP":12.8324,
  "BYN":2.8230,
  "BZD":2.0000,
  "CAD":1.3050,
  "CDF":1988.6057,
  "CHF":0.9782,
  "CLP":1047.4250,
  "CNY":6.7686,
  "COP":4573.0573,
  "CRC":686.8741,
  "CUP":24.0000,
  "CVE":109.5198,
  "CZK":24.2810,
  "DJF":177.7210,
  "DKK":7.4100,
  "DOP":54.7252,
  "DZD":147.0795,
  "EGP":18.8746,
  "ERN":15.0000,
  "ETB":51.8192,
  "EUR":0.9932,
  "FJD":2.2271,
  "FKP":0.8452,
  "FOK":7.4100,
  "GBP":0.8452,
  "GEL":2.8469,
  "GGP":0.8452,
  "GHS":8.3242,
  "GIP":0.8452,
  "GMD":53.9357,
  "GNF":8643.2884,
  "GTQ":7.7432,
  "GYD":208.4165,
  "HKD":7.8518,
  "HNL":24.5589,
  "HRK":7.4836,
  "HTG":114.4866,
  "HUF":398.6438,
  "IDR":14976.7866,
  "ILS":3.4749,
  "IMP":0.8452,
  "INR":79.8209,
  "IQD":1454.0600,
  "IRR":42056.7004,
  "ISK":138.3686,
  "JEP":0.8452,
  "JMD":151.4748,
  "JOD":0.7090,
  "JPY":138.7800,
  "KES":117.9526,
  "KGS":81.3321,
  "KHR":4065.7093,
  "KID":1.4762,
  "KMF":488.6430,
  "KRW":1321.7446,
  "KWD":0.2996,
  "KYD":0.8333,
  "KZT":480.8824,
  "LAK":16868.6002,
  "LBP":1507.5000,
  "LKR":356.0525,
  "LRD":152.3277,
  "LSL":17.0698,
  "LYD":4.8552,
  "MAD":9.9367,
  "MDL":19.3046,
  "MGA":4084.1272,
  "MKD":61.1373,
  "MMK":1834.4490,
  "MNT":3130.7286,
  "MOP":8.0873,
  "MRU":36.7687,
  "MUR":44.7852,
  "MVR":15.4430,
  "MWK":1033.6225,
  "MXN":20.6318,
  "MYR":4.4398,
  "MZN":64.4837,
  "NAD":17.0698,
  "NGN":413.4387,
  "NIO":35.8600,
  "NOK":10.1891,
  "NPR":127.7119,
  "NZD":1.6266,
  "OMR":0.3845,
  "PAB":1.0000,
  "PEN":3.9116,
  "PGK":3.5170,
  "PHP":56.3397,
  "PKR":209.4856,
  "PLN":4.7442,
  "PYG":6855.2462,
  "QAR":3.6400,
  "RON":4.8888,
  "RSD":116.5282,
  "RUB":57.7811,
  "RWF":1058.9331,
  "SAR":3.7500,
  "SBD":8.0297,
  "SCR":13.0412,
  "SDG":461.6883,
  "SEK":10.5059,
  "SGD":1.3978,
  "SHP":0.8452,
  "SLE":13.6370,
  "SLL":13636.9704,
  "SOS":576.2883,
  "SRD":22.3936,
  "SSP":544.8830,
  "STN":24.3344,
  "SYP":2526.6716,
  "SZL":17.0698,
  "THB":36.6993,
  "TJS":10.4715,
  "TMT":3.4981,
  "TND":2.8755,
  "TOP":2.3438,
  "TRY":17.4168,
  "TTD":6.7612,
  "TVD":1.4762,
  "TWD":29.8712,
  "TZS":2320.8657,
  "UAH":31.0508,
  "UGX":3768.5019,
  "UYU":40.3063,
  "UZS":10908.3372,
  "VES":5.6990,
  "VND":23432.6566,
  "VUV":119.1620,
  "WST":2.7261,
  "XAF":651.5240,
  "XCD":2.7000,
  "XDR":0.7635,
  "XOF":651.5240,
  "XPF":118.5255,
  "YER":249.9997,
  "ZAR":17.0702,
  "ZMW":16.4457,
  "ZWL":395.1049
 }
}
```

the line that produces the error

```
_exchangeRates.emit((it.data as Exchange).conversion_rates.toConversionItem())
```

The Errors I get

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testingxml.util.status.NetworkRequest$Success cannot be cast to com.example.testingxml.data.models.Exchange

> java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates$$serializer: com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates$$serializer.deserialize(kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder) failed to verify: com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates$$serializer.deserialize(kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder): [0x10F0] Rejecting invocation, expected 76 argument registers, method signature has 78 or more (declaration of 'com.example.testingxml.data.models.ConversionRates$$serializer' appears in /data/data/com.example.testingxml/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes7.dex)

> Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.testingxml/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory

*Update 2*

My Ktor Client:

```
object Client {

    val client = HttpClient(Android) {
        install(Logging) {

            logger = object : Logger {
                override fun log(message: String) {
                    Log.d(KTOR_CLIENT_LOGGER, message)
                }
            }
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            val converter = KotlinxSerializationConverter(Json {
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
            })
            register(Json, converter)
            register(ContentType.Application.OctetStream, converter)
        }

        engine {
            socketTimeout = KTOR_TIMEOUT
            connectTimeout = KTOR_TIMEOUT
            sslManager = { HttpsURLConnection ->
                HttpsURLConnection.sslSocketFactory = SslSettings.getSslContext()!!.socketFactory
            }
        }
        defaultRequest {
            contentType(Json)
        }
    }
}
```

My Repository

```
 override fun getAllFromApi(mainCurrency: String): Flow<RepositoryStatus> = flow {
        currencyApi.getCurrencyRate(mainCurrency).collect {networkRequest ->
            when (networkRequest) {
                is NetworkRequest.Failure -> emit(RepositoryStatus.Failure(networkRequest.error))
                is NetworkRequest.Success<*> -> emit(RepositoryStatus.Success(networkRequest))
            }
        }

    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

my Api

```
  override fun getCurrencyRate(mainCurrency: String): Flow<NetworkRequest> = flow {
        try {
            val result = client.get(Routes.Api.url.plus(mainCurrency))
            if (result.status == HttpStatusCode.OK) emit(NetworkRequest.Success(result.body<Exchange>()))
             else emit(NetworkRequest.Failure(result.toString()))
        }  catch  (e: ClientRequestException) {
            emit(NetworkRequest.Failure(e.message))
        } catch (e: ServerResponseException) {
            emit(NetworkRequest.Failure(e.message))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            emit(NetworkRequest.Failure(e.localizedMessage!!))
        } catch (e: SerializationException) {
            emit(NetworkRequest.Failure(e.localizedMessage!!))
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

Comment: What code are you calling that generates that error? What does the incoming JSON string look like? Can you add enough detail to the question so that someone else could fully reproduce your problem? [Maybe related bug](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1393), or [this one](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/632)

Comment: @TylerV like this?

Comment: Yeah, that helps - it sounds related to the two bugs I linked, but you have < 200 fields so maybe not?

Comment: around 165 fields...

Comment: @TylerV i checked the links and it seems that its the same issue, but what is the solution?

Comment: @TylerV
I changed the Serializer to GsonSerializer, and I got another problem io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException: No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel (Kotlin reflection is not available)

Comment: I tried your case, and although I was not able to generate the same error, if I used more than about 250 fields I did hit the error in that bug report. I confirmed that just using a `Map<String,Double>` had no such size limit, so that may work for you as well.

Comment: Can you make a totally standalone minimal unit test that reproduces the JSON error? (e.g. just put a hard-coded json string in and deserialize it, no retrofit or flows or anything else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/632) with the maximum number of fields supported by the automatic serialization routine.

Say you have a large data class (more than about 250 entries) to represent a nested object in a container class (like you have):

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class LargeData(
    val x1: String,
    val x2: String,
    val x3: String,
    val x4: String,
    //...
    val x258: String,
    val x259: String,
    val x260: String,
)

@Serializable
data class Container(
    val name: String,
    val rates: LargeData
)
```

When you attempt to serialize/deserialize it you will get an error about having too many arguments. To get around it, you could just store the data in a map then you can work with unlimited entries

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Container(
    val name: String,
    val rates: Map<String,Double>
)
```

In your case, you could just convert the large `ConversionRates` data class into a map, like this:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Exchange(
    val base_code: String,
    val conversion_rates: Map<String,Double>, // change this line, and remove the ConversionRates data class
    val documentation: String,
    val result: String,
    val terms_of_use: String,
    @PrimaryKey
    val time_last_update_unix: Int,
    val time_last_update_utc: String,
    val time_next_update_unix: Int,
    val time_next_update_utc: String
)
```

If you want to isolate the JSON part from the rest of your app, you could add a unit test that just takes a JSON string and checks that it can deserialize it

```kotlin
class JSONUnitTest {
    private val testJson = "{\"name\":\"some name\"}"

    @Test
    fun testJson()  {
        val t2 = Json.decodeFromString<Exchange>(testJson)
        println(t2)
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems there might something else hidden... I tried this solution before, including HashMap and TreeMap but same problem as now ->                                                                                                     java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testingxml.util.status.NetworkRequest$Success cannot be cast to com.example.testingxml.data.models.Exchange
... I want to add more info into the question

Comment: can you check my update?

Comment: Did you try just plain old "Map" (not "HashMap")? Can you add a standalone unit test that just takes a hard-coded JSON string and replicates the error?

Comment: yes i tried them all, including Map... I'm still learning to test but i will try...

Comment: I added a super simple example unit test to the answer that takes a json string and deserializes it. Doesn't actually test anything about the output, but it's a good way to help look for issues. If that works fine, then your issue is from some other interaction, not actually JSON conversion itself.

Comment: the solution was weird... I didn't emit the value i just assigned it and the error disappeared..